# Cannot display Angular dialog properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, reactjs

I am trying to make a dialog box in Angular, but the dialog is not been displayed in the centre, only as a vertical white rectangle to the left.
I will include an image depicting the exact problem: [screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaZFu.png).

1. I have included entry components in my `appmodule.ts` file
2. There are no errors while compiling it.

Header `component.ts` file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

 openLoginForm() {
    this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, {width: '500px', height: '450px'});
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added @angular/material styles to your project?

Comment: can you elaborate , i did not understand you

Comment: I've seen in the comments in @Santosh's answer that you've already added the styles. If this is a project where you're adding material, I suggest you go with `ng add @angular/material`. It does all the steps described in @angular/material getting started guide to add it to your project.If this is an Ivy project, there's no need for any `entryComponents` in the `NgModule` definition.

Answer (score 0):

add `LoginComponent` in `entrycomponents` array in `module`.

like this.

```
entryComponents: [LoginComponent]
```

Comment: Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-mat-dialog-example-data-sharing

Comment: i have already included LoginComponent  in entry Components

Comment: it is compiling succesfully without any error

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.

Comment: have you imported ```material css``` if not put this in global css ```style.css```  ```@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';```

Comment: i have imported this also in the global styles.css file

Comment: then abort compilation and compile again

Comment: should i delete node_modules and reinstall? because i have aborted and recompiled a few times now

Comment: have a look in demo and check what is missing https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-mat-dialog-example-data-sharing

Comment: i am not able to find any errors
i have uploaded the files on git can you quickly have a look https://github.com/Sameerdhole/first